# Chrome omnibox search shortcut with 2 inputs?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to create multi-variable search shortcut?

Google Search Trends lets me compare multiple terms, e.g. "foo" vs "bar." Here's the URL: `http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=foo#q=bar&cmpt=q`

Is there a way to make typing "gst foo bar" in the Chrome omnibox direct me to the same URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you cannot use complicated string format for your Omnibox search term, you can use `commas` to compare different search keywords.

Simply create a new search shortcut with the keyword `gst` and the following URL

`http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=%s&cmpt=q`

[image: Search shortcut]

then separate your keywords with a comma

[image: Search terms]

You will end up with this result

[image: Google Search Term result]